# Reducibility of polynomial in rational field

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n>0$. Let $p_1, p_2, \dots ,p_{n+1}$ be distinct prime numbers. Show that there exists a non-zero polynomial $g(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $fg=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} c_ix^{p_i}$ with every $c_i\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Consider the images of the $x^{p_i}$ in the quotient ring $\Bbb Q[X]/(f(X))$.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232316/polynomial-rings-and-prime-numbers.